# Is it possible to use Observable Data Table Cell in Quarto?

Tags: r, quarto, observablehq

I would like to use `Observable` `Data Table Cell` for its superb filtering capabilities and data summaries, but I would like to use it in `Quarto` documents. Is it possible?

It seems to me that it is, unfortunately, not possible. I tried to import it using `import` and also to embed it in Quarto as html, but both of these options only allow me to import/embed the underlying dataset, not the data table cell.

This is what I want.
[image]

But I get only this.
[image]

````
---
title: "Data Table Cell"
---

Using import
```{ojs}
import {datTbl} from "@novotny1akub/ojstbl"

datTbl

```

Using html code from Embed
```{=html}
<div id="observablehq-datTbl-5d27bed1"></div>
<p>Credit: <a href="https://observablehq.com/@novotny1akub/ojstbl@156">Data Table Cell by novotny1akub</a></p>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@observablehq/inspector@5/dist/inspector.css">
<script type="module">
import {Runtime, Inspector} from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@observablehq/runtime@5/dist/runtime.js";
import define from "https://api.observablehq.com/@novotny1akub/ojstbl@156.js?v=3";
new Runtime().module(define, name => {
  if (name === "datTbl") return new Inspector(document.querySelector("#observablehq-datTbl-5d27bed1"));
});
</script>

```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Data Table Cell is a feature of the Observable website  not the OJS language. It is not available in Quarto.